# Show that $\chi{'}(T) = \Delta(T)$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

My attempted proof:

- We know that every bipartite graph $G$ has $\chi{'}(G) = \Delta(G)$
- And then i showed that every tree is a bipartite graph by induction on the number of vertices in T.

T denoting a tree.    $\chi^{'}$ denoting the chromatic index.

Is This a correct approach ?

Comment: AFAIS $T$ is a tree, but anyway you need to write this explicitly. And what is $\chi'$?

Comment: It's the chromatic index

Comment: There are a bunch of things in math that are denoted by $\Delta,\chi$ or $T$. How do you expect for others to understand what is stated here?

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct.

Comment: @Wolfram i realize that, my apologies. I edited the post.